# ios sequence viewControllers with same blur or transparent background

Tags: ios, transparent, viewcontroller

How create sequence of `UIViewController` with same `UINavigationViewController` with transparent background

I write

```
ProfileViewController *viewController = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But while showing animation background of `viewController` is transparent, but after transparent is gone

I saw how to show one view with `addSubview`, but I have sequence of `uiviewcontrollers`.

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor colorWithHue:0.555f saturation:1.f brightness:0.855f alpha:1.f]; add this code to your rootViewController !